# Excel Power Query Sequel Source Code explanation

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

Hi learned colleagues,

I have an Excel Power Query I hae inherited I am trying to edit. The Source it pulls from is our Sage Sequel Database where we have approx 15 different entities databases and have a table as follows named SageCompanyTable (B1 to C9) that it reads for whichever entity database is selected from a list.

[image: SageCompanyTable]

The Code in the Query has the beginning code referring to the Source Database and the SageCompanyTable

```
 Source = Sql.Database("MVXX\Sage200", SageCompanyTable, [Query="SELECT DISTINCT #(lf)                         SourceSystem, AccountNumber, AccountCostCentre, AccountDepartment, AccountNumber + AccountCostCentre + AccountDepartment AS FullAccCode, AccountName, Code,
..........
```

It carries on with all the columns code etc.

It must be reading cell C3 in the SageCompanyTable (in the row alongside "Database" for the selected Source Database to pull the data from.

The Query works, but I need make some edit modifications.

My question please is what within that initial Source Code tells it to read the selected database, in the example above "UK_XXXXDBase"?
My thoughts are is direct Sequel Code, is it just that it looks in the SageCompanyTable Table and finds per the code a match for one of the Sequel Databases where it reads "Source = Sql.Database(......)

Many thanks
Gary

Answer (score 0):

apologies, just answered my own Question, the Query is linked to a Connection Query called "SageCompanyTable" that reads the Database Cell in the Table.